# How can I activate a touchableOpacity or other react-native component by dragging over it?

Tags: react-native

I am working on a grid view that consists of touchable opacities side by side.  I would like to be able to drag across them and active the onPress function for each.  Any ideas?  I haven't found anything that works.
Thanks!